# Can't install pepperflashplugin-nonfree package

Tags: 18.04, apt, dpkg, flash

Recently I encountered a problem every time I try to install a new package on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer. The installer is always stuck at `Setting up pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1) ...` I left the computer for like 15 minutes but it was still 0% Processing, even when I tried the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

My computer:

- Asus ROG G512
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Using Chrome browser: Version 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Screenshot
[image]

Appreciate all your support.

Comment: Is this a flash plugin if so flash is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to flash no longer support, so the installer is trying to download something that not exists. So I have to remove the flash by this command: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

Everything is fine now.
Hope this can help.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Was it the Spotify `.deb` package you installed? Does that package recommend `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`?

Comment: Yes, it was spotify that I tried to install. Actually, no, it doesn't.  I removed 'pepperflashplugin-nonfree' and install Spotify again. It is working fine now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Then, once you have tried to install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`, it blocks all installation until you remove that package. It would be helpful if you could add a comment on [this bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1871471).